# !< in Javascript - How to set my condition to run only when the user is not under 18?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I want to set the condition to be, if its not less than 18 than elegible to vote else not eligible. Spend over an hour but can't figure it out. I think the problem is in the placement of ! operator. Some of the combinations that I have tried are the following:

if(eligible! < 18)

if(!eligible < 18)

if(!eligible >= 18)

Here is the code I am working on.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test a logical NOT condition</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var eligible = Number(prompt("How old are you?", 20));

    if (eligible! < 18) {
      document.write("You are eligible to enrol to vote.");
    } else {
      document.write("You are too young to vote. Come back when you are 18");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not less than is more or equal to and vise versa. (`eligible >= 18`)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misplacing the `!`.

```
if(!(eligible < 18))
```

What you wrote is actually checking `eligible` is not 0. The same as:

```
if((!eligible) < 18))
```

You need to place the `!` token *before* the condition you want to check too.

Comment: Why so complicated?
!(eligible < 18) == eligible >= 18

Comment: @Marcel Burkhard meh ?

Comment: @Luca How is `if(!(eligible < 18))` more readable than `if(eligible >= 18)`?

Comment: @George at first glance his answer reads as `!(eligible < 18) == eligible >= 18` . Your comment to the OP's question is great and clear, PinkTurtle's answer addresses the OP's need to understand how `!` works. My comment just asked for syntax highlight of the code!

Comment: @Luca I misunderstood your comment, apologies.